# Nginx Url Beautify with Rewrite

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Currently i have my own domain example like abc.com, but when i click another page in abc.com i saw that the url have too much thing then i expected, 
code like below

```
abc.com/index.html?utm_expid=122964311-0.Ij_8kYLEQneeCz7Rwkt0HA.0&utm_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.abc.com%2Fpartner.html
```

may i know how can i rewrite using nginx to make it beautiful?

nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name abc.com www.abc.com;
    root    /web/abc/www/phone/;
    index   index.php index.cgi index.pl index.html index.htm;

    charset utf-8;
    access_log  logs/abc.access.log ;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
    }
```

please help, thanks in advanced.

Comment: Please explain what the end result should look like. Realistically you can only remove index.html Those parameters seem part of some form of tracking.

Comment: ok, so may i know how can i remove the index.html?

Answer (score 2):

The URLs in abc.com are generated by the application software running on it, or tracking scripts you get from an external source.

You cannot use nginx to make anything to those URLs, since nginx only handles URLs that come to the server, not the URLs that the application software generates.